# How to know if “About This Mac” got modded and/or reset it

Tags: macbook-pro

I've seen plenty of articles about how its kinda easy to mod the "About this mac" section, however, I was wondering if I where to buy a mac from a stranger, what is a quick way to check the real specs and date of release without having to reset to factory settings.

It must be something quick so I can check it before paying for it without taking too much time.

Answer (score 3):

Each Mac's serial number should be printed on the outside of the casing.

1. Locate the serial number. Apple provide instructions on [how to locate the serial numbers on their devices here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204308).
2. And then enter the serial number on Apple's [Service and Support Coverage](https://selfsolve.apple.com/) to find out the real model and age of the device.